# trying to sum two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to code something like this:

[image: link]

where `x` and `y` are two different `numpy` arrays and the `j` is an index for the array. I don't know the length of the array because it will be entered by the user and I cannot use loops to code this.

My main problem is finding a way to move between indexes since i would need to go from

```
x[2]-x[1] ... x[3]-x[2]
```

and so on.

I'm stumped but I would appreciate any clues.

Comment: Look into `numpy.diff` and then sum up.

Answer (score 2):

A numpy-ic solution would be:

```
np.square(np.diff(x)).sum() + np.square(np.diff(y)).sum()
```

A list comprehension approach would be:

```
sum([(x[k]-x[k-1])**2+(y[k]-y[k-1])**2 for k in range(1,len(x))])
```

will give you the result you want, even if your data appears as list.

Answer (score 0):

`x[2]-x[1] ... x[3]-x[2]` can be generalized to:

```
x[[1,2,3,...]-x[[0,1,2,...]]
x[1:]-x[:-1]       # ie. (1 to the end)-(0 to almost the end)
```

`numpy` can take the difference between two arrays of the same shape

In list terms this would be

```
[i-j for i,j in zip(x[1:], x[:-1])]
```

`np.diff` does essentially this, `a[slice1]-a[slice2]`, where the `slices` are as above.

The full answer squares, sums and squareroots.